# iOS: how to allow all gestures/events *with a couple exceptions* to pass through a top level view to its subviews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have an atypical iOS interface. Perhaps it's not practical but I'm giving it a go. Hope someone can help!

I have a menu in the form of a UIVIew. It contains 5 small UIImageViews. A UIPinchGestureRecognizer is attached to the UIVIew. When pinched inward, the 5 UIImageViews animate from off screen to form a circle in the middle of the window. When pinched outward, they animate back offscreen. Everything works great there.

I'd like to be able to, at any point in the application, pinch the screen to reveal the menu, select one of the 'buttons' (UIImageView), and load the associated subview.

The real problem is, if the current visible view is a UIScrollView or UITableView, my app is having trouble figuring out whether the menu or other subview should handle the touch event. If I really focus and make sure two finger touch the screen at the EXACT same time, the pinch will work and pull the menu inward. But otherwise, it attempts to scroll the current visible view.

I would like all events except the pinch gesture, (and a tap gesture when the menu is visible), to pass through the menu view to the rest of the subviews.

I understand I can override the hitTest:withEvent method to determine the correct view to handle the event, but I'm unclear at this point how exactly to use it. Neither the Apple docs nor any answers I've read on stack overflow have made this method clear to me.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView, it inherits all of UIScrollView's properties including its gesture recognisers.

UIScrollView declares a UIPinchGestureRecognizer and UIPanGestureRecognizer. I'm not sure of the implementation details but I imagine the UITableView disables the pinch gesture recogniser as you are not supposed to be able to zoom a tableview!

In any case, you can attach your own UIPinchGestureRecognizer to the table view:

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *yPGR = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]
initWithTarget:probablySelf action:yourMenuShowSelectorHere];

UITableView *tv = ...
// ...
[tv addGestureRecognizer:yPGR];
```

Then, you can make sure that the UITableView scoll does NOT scroll until your pinch has failed:

```
[tv.panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:yPGR];
```

This way, the UITableView will not scroll until it is sure that it has not detected a pinch.

EDIT: UIScrollView only uses (or at least declares public access to) UIGestureRecognizers in iOS 5 and up.